# subscript Array change coordinates

Tags: ios, swift

How can I change subscript coordinates in an Array of `Arrays [[Int]]` so that the way to address a cell would be `table[column-letter][row-number]`, same as Excel, instead of current ios `table[row-number][column-number]` for a given table like:

```
var table = [[0,  1,  2,  3],
             [1, 32, 44, 25],
             [2, 12, 66, 43],
             [3,  3,  4,  5]]
```

Today `table[2][1] = 12`, but I want `table[C][1] = 44`.

I need this change to adapt formulas from excel into my app without changing the coordinate system or the tables from an Excel.

I know there are subscript functions in Array class which may help, but I couldn´t make it work so far.

Comment: You can use the character value of the column and subtract "A" to get a 0 based integer

Comment: @Paulw11 do you think somehow another option could be Bitmask ?

Comment: Not really.  My example is only the trivial case. For true "excel" behaviour you need to parse longer column names such as "AA" which is the 27th column and so on. There are also absolute and relative column/row specifications. To be honest, I wouldn't be using a multi dimensional array to represent a spreadsheet. Something that wraps or emulates a sparse array would be better; a DAG or dictionary

Answer (score 0):

> Today table[2](https://medium.com/devslopes-blog/learning-swift-and-ios-development-part-7-dictionaries-d10b20573df3) = 12, but I want table[C](https://medium.com/devslopes-blog/learning-swift-and-ios-development-part-7-dictionaries-d10b20573df3) = 44.

Do you know what is `[2][1]`  actually means you are telling the compiler,

i want the element in the array that has index of `[2]` and by adding another `[1]`, you are telling it that you need the element that has index of `[1]` that its inside the result of `[2]`.

its an `Array` of `Arrays`  if you take another look at it empty would be something like this ,

```
[[],[],[]] // no matter what is the values inside indexing is always the same
```

with that pointed out now lets take a look on what are you trying to do.

```
[C][1] = 44
```

As you can now probably tell this is not valid because `[C]` is not a valid index as index accept only `Integer` Types.

So what can we try ?.

Well you can try dictionaries 
Read about them [here](https://medium.com/devslopes-blog/learning-swift-and-ios-development-part-7-dictionaries-d10b20573df3)

With dictionary at some point  you will be able to get a value like this

```
value = table["C"]?[1]
```

or take a look on this example.

```
var foo :[String:[Int]] = ["A":[1,2,3], "B":[1,2,3]]
let colm = foo["A"]?[0]
```

Edit another solution inspired by  @Paulw11

using this `"A".utf16.first! - 65` will return 0 `index` to use inside the Array so you can additionally say from **A to Z**

```
table = ["MyChar".utf16.first! - 65][2]
```

Comment: The dictionary option [String: [Int]], I already tested it as it would be a simple option, the issue is that for each letter, it would address a Row, but I need to address a Column, as in Excel the letters are columns, and not rows, not sure if my comment is clear for you

Comment: var table: [String: [Int]] = [
                "X":  [0,  1,   2,  3],
                "A":  [0, 30, 344, 25],
                "B":  [0, 12,  66, 43],
                "C":  [0,  3,   4,  5]
    ]

Comment: Another issue with dictionaries: they are unordered, so no warrant that row "B" would go after row "A", so for long worksheets it would be a nightmare

Comment: how are you creating the arrays ? dynamically, or manually inserting them

Comment: the arrange dose not matter as long as you trying to index using the Charachter key !!

Comment: Tobi the arrays are manual, just plain numbers in a spreadsheet as in the example but many more numbers

Comment: well dictionary should solve it as when u access a character then it will access its array !